# How can I display different languages in a custom bottom bar and Drop List in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, internationalization, intl

I'm using ARB files along with code generation for my internalization solution for my flutter app. Everything seems to be work as expecting, but I do have one problem. I can't get the options in the drop down lists and my bottom bar to switch languages.

Here is my locale.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:manchester_maps/l10n/messages_all.dart';

class AppLocalizations {
  static Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    final String name =
        locale.countryCode.isEmpty ? locale.languageCode : locale.toString();

    final String localeName = Intl.canonicalizedLocale(name);

    return initializeMessages(localeName).then((bool _) {
      Intl.defaultLocale = localeName;
      return AppLocalizations();
    });
  }

  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  String get title {
    return Intl.message(
      'Manchester Maps',
      name: 'title',
      desc: 'The name of the application',
    );
  }

  String get pageTitleMyPlaces {
    return Intl.message('My Places',
        name: 'pageTitleMyPlaces', desc: 'The My Places Title');
  }

  String get pageTitleSafetyInfo {
    return Intl.message('Safety Info',
        name: 'pageTitleSafetyInfo', desc: 'The Safety Info Title');
  }

  String get pageTitleSettings {
    return Intl.message('Settings',
        name: 'pageTitleSettings', desc: 'The Safety Info Title');
  }

  String get drawerResidences {
    return Intl.message('Residences',
        name: 'drawerResidences',
        desc: 'The Residences option on the sliding nav bar');
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...


class AppLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return ['en', 'es', 'fr', 'hi', 'ar', 'ru', 'zh', 'ja']
        .contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) {
    return AppLocalizations.load(locale);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(AppLocalizationsDelegate old) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I have a number of Lists (see below) and this is where I am having issues.

In the code below, I have an error with the context.

```
    class _SettingsFormState extends State<SettingsForm> {
  // TODO: Change this to retrieve data from local database
  bool _allowTilt = true;
  bool _enableRotate = true;
  bool _enableZoom = true;
  bool _showTraffic = false;
  bool _showCompass = true;

  // Properties for Theme Timing. This denotes whether the theme switches
  //  from day to night automatically at sunset and sunrise times
  List<String> _themeTiming = [**AppLocalizations.of(context).settingsDDLThemeDay**, 'Night', 'Auto'];
  String _selectedThemeTiming;
  // List of Day Themes
  List<String> _dayTheme = [
    'Standard',
    'Retro',
    'Simple Bright',
    'Map Posters',
    'Bentley',
    'Clean Cut'
  ];
  String _selectedDayTheme;
  // List of Night Themea
  List<String> _nightTheme = [
    'Night',
    'Simple Night',
    'Dark',
    'Midnight Commander',
    'Aubergine',
    'Cobalt'
  ];
  String _selectedNightTheme;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
            ...
            ...
            ...
```

Any help with this is appreciated as it is driving me nuts.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using the translations in your List, it should be

```dart
  List<String> _dayTheme = [
    AppLocalizations.standard,
    AppLocalizations.retro,
    AppLocalizations.simpleBright,
    AppLocalizations.mapPosters,
    AppLocalizations.bentley,
    AppLocalizations.cleanCut
  ];
```

Where you define all of `standard, retro ...`etc inside of your AppLocalization file

Comment: Hi Julien, thanks for commenting. I've shown an example in how I have been using it in the themeTiming List (see code above). There is an error on the word "context) - AppLocalizations.of(context).settingsDDLThemeDay

thanks

Comment: aaaah. Well just declare `List<String> _themeTiming` and assign the value inside the class' `initState` method, because you can't access `context` from properties

Comment: Hi Julien, That got rid of the context error, but how do I display that in the dropdownMenuITem? It now says  _themeTiming is not being used.

Comment: You don't show how to provide values for this menu. But you need to translate the messages the way I explained in this answer, otherwise you'll always see the hardcoded strings

Comment: Using AppLocalizations just didn't work in the list, but once I changed I used separate  menu items, then that worked perfectly.

Not sure how I'm going to get the bottom bar working though.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe you should post your findings as an answer to your question, it may be helpful for people landing on your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add the localizations to my dropdown buttons by moving the options out of a list and adding them directly into the DropdownButton. It has increased the amount of code, but they are fully multi-lingual now. I've not been able to figure out getting the bottom bar multi-lingual yet, but progress has been made. Hopefully this will help.

```
Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).settingsLabelDayTheme),
// DAY THEME DROP DOWN LIST
DropdownButton(
hint: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
    .settingsDDLDayThemeHint),
items: [
  DropdownMenuItem(
    value: "standard",
    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
        .settingsDDLDayTheme1),
  ),
  DropdownMenuItem(
    value: "retro",
    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
        .settingsDDLDayTheme2),
  ),
  DropdownMenuItem(
    value: "simple_bright",
    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
        .settingsDDLDayTheme3),
  ),
  DropdownMenuItem(
    value: "map_posters",
    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
        .settingsDDLDayTheme4),
  ),
  DropdownMenuItem(
    value: "bentley",
    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
        .settingsDDLDayTheme5),
  ),
  DropdownMenuItem(
    value: "clean_cut",
    child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)
        .settingsDDLDayTheme6),
  ),
],
onChanged: (dayTheme) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedDayTheme = dayTheme;
  });
},
value: _selectedDayTheme,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried everything to work it out. And the solution worked for me was adding localizations directly into DropDownMenu. Not pulling them as list from somewhere else.